# HTTP ERROR 500?

Tags: apache

I'm trying to set up my project on xampp.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin test@test.biz
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/public"
    ServerName testproject.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I uncomment line in httpd.conf for virtual hosts, but stil im getting error 500. Any suggestion? I m using MAC OS.

Also in hosts i added:

```
127.0.0.1 testproject.dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any suggestion?

It's impossible to help you without checking the log. You should enable Apache HTTP Server's logging and check the events. I guess that the log in your case is `dummy-host2.example.com-error_log`. Look through the events and find out what's wrong with this configuration.

Comment: how to enable apache logging?